# Type 'double' with column and row information in console does not appear correctly when using View()

Tags: r, dataframe, double

Something strange (to me) is going on.

I have time series data collected by running the commands

```
data.ts = ts(1:10, frequency = 4, start = c(1959, 2))
D = decompose(data.ts)
df = D$trend
```

I have what I thought was a data frame (but is actually of type `double`), df, that when executed in the console, looks like

```
>df
     Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
1959        NA   NA    3
1960    4    5    6    7
1961    8   NA   NA
```

However, when using `View(df)`, the data looks like the following below (and does not have the years or quarter information with it):

```
>View(df)
    z
1    NA
2    NA
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    NA
10   NA
```

I have been trying to converting this type `double` (it is not a ts object to a data frame that looks like the result I'm getting currently in the console, but using `as.data.frame(df)` converts df to a data frame that looks like the 2 column example from earlier.

1. What is going on exactly?
2. Bonus: How do I create a data frame out of df while keeping the months and years intact?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data that we can copy/paste to run and test. But the basic problem is that View expects a data.frame and `df` is a` ts` (time series) object, not a data.frame.

Comment: Fixed for reproducibility, and I wanted to note as well that what I'm working with is not a `ts` object, it is a `double` created through the above code, using `decompose` and `trend`.

Comment: Are you using `typeof` to get at type? That's not really a helpful function. What you ususally want is `class` to see how an object behaves and `class(df)` returns "ts" so it is a time series object.

Comment: Why do you need it as a data.frame?

Comment: I'm looking to use it to see through an earlier question I had:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45695160/plotting-a-subset-of-sequential-time-series-data-in-r

The frame of that question was a data frame. When I tried to execute it as is I got an error, but it works as a data frame. Thank you re: typeof vs class, by the way.